# Sending Plain text emails using PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, formatting, phpmailer, plaintext

I have a problem sending plain text emails using PHPMailer.

I have text that I read from a text file and mail it to mail recipient via PHPMailer

When the recipient gets the actual email, the formatting of the mail is not like in the text file, everything is in one line, no new lines and tabs are included in the email that I send.  Text wrapping is totally off.

Code:

```
        $mail->ContentType = 'text/plain'; 
        $mail->IsHTML(false);
        $address = "test@test.com";
        $mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");

        $mail->SetFrom(EMAIL_TEST_FROM);

        $mail->AddReplyTo(EMAIL_TEST_REPLY);



        $mail->Subject = $action." REGISTRATION ".$formName.$tld;
        $mail->From = EMAIL_TEST;  

        $mail->MsgHTML(file_get_contents($newFile));


        if($mail->Send()){
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: It's a domain registration file, whois.co.za, but the problem has been sorted. Thx James

Comment: You can simplify the `if($mail->Send())` part to `return $mail->Send();`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are setting `$mail->MsgHTML()` to a plain text message, and since whitespace formatting is ignored in HTML, you're getting an inline text.

I haven't used PHPMailer for a while, but from memory try:

```
$mail->Body = file_get_contents($newFile);
```

Answer (score 13):

```
    $mail->ContentType = 'text/plain'; 
    $mail->IsHTML(false);
    $address = "test@test.com";
    $mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");

    $mail->SetFrom(EMAIL_TEST_FROM);

    $mail->AddReplyTo(EMAIL_TEST_REPLY);



    $mail->Subject = $action." REGISTRATION ".$formName.$tld;
    $mail->From = EMAIL_TEST;  

    // Very important: don't have lines for MsgHTML and AltBody 
    $mail->Body = file_get_contents($mailBodyTextFile);  
    // $mail->Body = $_POST["msg"];  //If using web mail form, use this line instead.


    if($mail->Send()){
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: +1 for the explaination of what lines to exclude as well as what to include to trigger text-only.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code which works fine:

```
        try {
            $mail->AddAddress('jitpal@domain.com', 'Jit Pal');
            $mail->SetFrom('testuser@domain.com', 'Test User');
            $mail->Subject = "All machine's tests.";
            $mail->Body = "All machine's tests working fine.";
            $mail->Send();
            echo "<br/>Message sent successfully...<br/><br/>\n";
        } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
            echo $e->errorMessage();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
```